# Write Lines to New File Based off of Speaker

Tags: regex, python-3.x, text-parsing

I have a debate file which looks like the following (bold is added for clearer reading):

> **TAPPER:** Senator Rubio?
>   **RUBIO:** Every election is important. I believe this is the most important election in a generation. Because what's at stake in this election is not simply what party is going to be in charge or which candidate wins. What's at stake is our identity as a nation and as a people.
>   **RUBIO:** For over two centuries, America has been an exceptional nation. And now the time has come for this generation to do what it must do to keep it that way. If we make the right choice in this election, our children are going to be the freest and most prosperous Americans that have ever lived. And the 21st century is going to be a new American century.
>   (APPLAUSE)
>   **TAPPER:** Senator Cruz?
>   **CRUZ:** Fifty-nine years ago, Florida welcomed my father to America as he stepped off the ferry boat from Cuba onto Key West. He was 18. He was filled with hopes and dreams, and yet he was in the freest land on the face of the earth.
>   This election, this debate is not about insults. It's not about attacks. It's not about any of the individuals on this stage. This election is about you and your children. It's about the freedom America has always had and making sure that that freedom is there for the next generation, that we stop Washington from standing in the way of the hard-working taxpayers of America.
>   (APPLAUSE)
>   **TAPPER:** Mr. Trump?
>   **TRUMP:** One of the biggest political events anywhere in the world is happening right now with the Republican Party. Millions and millions of people are going out to the polls and they're voting. They're voting out of enthusiasm. They're voting out of love. Some of these people, frankly, have never voted before - 50 years old, 60 years old, 70 years old - never voted before.
>   We're taking people from the Democrat Party. We're taking people as independents, and they're all coming out and the whole world is talking about it. It's very exciting. I think, frankly, the Republican establishment, or whatever you want to call it, should embrace what's happening.
>   We're having millions of extra people join. We are going to beat the Democrats. We are going to beat Hillary or whoever it may be. And we're going to beat them soundly.
>   (APPLAUSE)

I want to create two files out of this one text file: one with all the speech which Cruz has said, the other a file which is just the text Trump has said. Any idea how? I've tried the following regex which allows me to find the text of each line the candidate said, but not the following line if it's broken up by a newline.

```
import re

with open('RepDebate_FL.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        cruz_regex = str(re.findall(r'CRUZ:.*', line))
        trump_regex = str(re.findall(r'TRUMP:.*', line))
        if cruz_regex is not None:
            print(cruz_regex)
```

Meaning I get this line:

['CRUZ: Fifty-nine years ago, Florida welcomed my father to America as he stepped off the ferry boat from Cuba onto Key West. He was 18. He was filled with hopes and dreams, and yet he was in the freest land on the face of the earth.']

But the next is blank, because it's broken by newline and doesn't begin with 
'CRUZ:':

[]

Any and all help is appreciated, TIA.

Comment: don't use regexes, really. just read a line, check if it starts with trump/cruz, and write out to the appropriate file if so. keep track of the last speaker name seen, and keep dumping text into the same file, until the speaker changes.

Comment: it might be worth doing something with `re.split(r"^[A-Z]{2,}", ...)` but I don't have the time to test it at the moment.

Comment: @MarcB how would I check if it starts with trump/cruz?

Comment: `if (substr($line, 0, 6) == 'TRUMP:')` is easy enough. regexes are handy, but just for checking if a line starts with one of two things, they're overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split` and the itertools `grouper` recipe for this.

```
import itertools
import re

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    iters = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*iters, fillvalue=fillvalue)

s = filter(None, re.split(r"([A-Z]+:)", the_text))
pairs = grouper(s, 2)
```

this leaves `pairs` as:

```
('TAPPER:', ' Senator Rubio?\n')
('RUBIO:', " Every election is important. I believe this is the most important election in a generation. Because what's at stake in this election is not simply what party is going to be in charge or which candidate wins. What's at stake is our identity as a nation and as a people.\n")
('RUBIO:', ' For over two centuries, America has been an exceptional nation. And now the time has come for this generation to do what it must do to keep it that way. If we make the right choice in this election, our children are going to be the freest and most prosperous Americans that have ever lived. And the 21st century is going to be a new American century.\n(APPLAUSE)\n')
('TAPPER:', ' Senator Cruz?\n')
('CRUZ:', " Fifty-nine years ago, Florida welcomed my father to America as he stepped off the ferry boat from Cuba onto Key West. He was 18. He was filled with hopes and dreams, and yet he was in the freest land on the face of the earth.\nThis election, this debate is not about insults. It's not about attacks. It's not about any of the individuals on this stage. This election is about you and your children. It's about the freedom America has always had and making sure that that freedom is there for the next generation, that we stop Washington from standing in the way of the hard-working taxpayers of America.\n(APPLAUSE)\n")
('TAPPER:', ' Mr. Trump?\n')
('TRUMP:', " One of the biggest political events anywhere in the world is happening right now with the Republican Party. Millions and millions of people are going out to the polls and they're voting. They're voting out of enthusiasm. They're voting out of love. Some of these people, frankly, have never voted before - 50 years old, 60 years old, 70 years old - never voted before. We're taking people from the Democrat Party. We're taking people as independents, and they're all coming out and the whole world is talking about it. It's very exciting. I think, frankly, the Republican establishment, or whatever you want to call it, should embrace what's happening. We're having millions of extra people join. We are going to beat the Democrats. We are going to beat Hillary or whoever it may be. And we're going to beat them soundly.\n(APPLAUSE)")
```

Then we just iterate and check speaker name.

```
for speaker, body in pairs:
    if "TRUMP" in speaker:
        # write body to trump file
    elif "CRUZ" in speaker:
        # write body to cruz file
```